# Why aren’t the magnitude comparators cascaded the “more efficient” way?

Tags: comparator, digital-comparator

In *Practical Electronics for Inventors*, Paul shows the following cascading of two \$ 74HC85 \$’s to build an 8-bit magnitude comparator.[image]

**Question:** Why doesn’t he cascade them in the apparently more efficient way where the higher order bits are compared first?

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? If you'd feed the more significat 4 bits to the left comparator and the less significant bits to the right comparator it would be just wrong, not more efficient.

Comment: @Curd He is mistaking things drawn on the right as necessarily happening later than things on the left, with his logic being that if you compare the MSB first, you might be able to ignore the LSB, while forgetting that the output is actually already next to the MSB.

Comment: @DKNguyen: if this is the case OP isn't even wrong: first the output of the left IC has to be settled before the right IC can come to a final decision. Just like addition/subtraction comparision can't be parallisized: the less significant bits have to be processed before the more significant ones; Not vice versa.

Comment: @Curd Actually the LSB output doesn't always have to be settled first due to don't cares. See my answer. Another problem was that the OP didn't realize that the compare and cascade inputs have a fixed hierarchy of dominance. In his mind they seemed to just order thmselves "as necessary for the situation" which is part of what led to his misconception. His method required a reverse hierarchy of what the chip has.

Comment: @DKNguyen: yes, if MSBits differ then LSBits don't have to be checked at all; but what matters is the worst case (with respect to dependencies) and that's when MSBits are equal.

Comment: @Curd Fair enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the comparing inputs can dominate/override the cascaded inputs, not vice versa. That means the MSB which should be dominant during comparison must be compared in the last stage prior to output in order to actually be dominant.

Also, even if the IC was constructed so cascaded inputs override compare inputs, your way is less efficient. It's already more efficient this way. The output stage can act directly on the dominant MSB and can ignore the LSBs if they won't make a difference. Your way, the dominating MSB comparison result must cascade all the way through the LSB comparison ICs to get to the output.

Graphically, it might look like MSB is compared last because it is on the right, but that' just drawn so input to output moves from left to right. In actuality, the numerical bits get fed to all ICs at the same time and the cascade lags behind that. So all numerical bits are being compared at the same time and the MSB comparison can act the quickest since it can ignore the cascading LSB results to get the output out the door.

[image]

NXP 74HC85 Datasheet

Comment: Thanks! That really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Atom, for a simple equal-or-not-equal magnitude comparison you are correct.  The bits can be assigned in any order, including randomly, as long as they are the same for the A and B inputs.  But things change with the < and > determinations.  Now the bit-assignments within the logic must be a strict order such that each stage is more significant than all preceding stages.  True, this can be done with the comparison path going either "uphill" or "downhill".  But the internal logic is less complex with uphill expansion (each additional stage is more significant than the previous stage).  Also it means you get double duty out of the three control bits.  For intermediate stages they are outputs to the next higher stage, and for the highest stage they are global comparison results.